# Asymptotic Expansion of Integrals via Integration by Parts - Leading Behavior

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, approximation

I'm trying to find the leading behavior of

$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{t}dt, \qquad x \rightarrow 0^+$$

Two applications of integration by parts gives

$$\frac{-\sin x}{x} + \frac{\cos x}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} \int_1^\infty 2t^{-3} \cos(xt) dt$$

So, I believe the leading behavior is just the first two terms, but I would have to be able to show

$$ \int_1^\infty 2t^{-3} \cos(xt) dt \ll \int_1^\infty t^{-1}\cos(xt)\ dt, \qquad  x \rightarrow 0^+$$

Is my reasoning correct? If so, how do I conclude this?

Comment: The integral $\int_1^\infty 2t^{-3}\cos(xt)dt$ is bounded, but this does not help as $x\to0+$ as the last term might wipe out the others. This approach would work for $x\to\infty$. Here, I propose a substitution $u=xt$. The behavior of $\int_x^\infty \frac{cos(u)}u du$, $x\to0$ can be found by classical means. Not unexpectedly, I find as main term $-\ln(x)$.

Comment: $$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x t)}{t}\,dt = -\gamma-\log(x)+\frac{x^2}{4}+o(x^3)$$ as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: To complete my previous comment, let me remark that the integral in question is related to the [cosine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral): $\int_x^\infty\frac{\cos(u)}udu=-Ci(x)$.

Comment: I missed that the question was asking about $x \to 0$, so I deleted my answer.